# How do I get the imageView's frame size during cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use a `UITableViewController` with a XIB, not a Storyboard, and use the default style: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.  I want to set the default `imageView`'s `cornerRadius` to the `imageView`'s width / 2, but during `cellForRowAtIndexPath()` the `imageView` is 0,0,0,0.

I remember reading somewhere that the frame doesn't get updated until it is added to the sub view.

How to I get the `imageView.frame.size.width`?  The `UITableView` is showing the rows correctly, but the `cornerRadius` is 0.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Set Image
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(imageLiteral: "\(indexPath.row).jpg")

    // FOLLOWING DOESNT WORK imageView is 0,0,0,0
    cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.frame.size.width / 2 

    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    // Set Label
    let name:String = contactsArray![indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.textLabel!.text = name

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, did you give your imageView a placeholder image or a height/width constraint?

Comment: No. Since this is in a XIB, I cannot use prototype cells and Im not using a custom cell XIB either.  All I did was register the default UITableViewCell in viewDidLoad: tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContactCell").  Nothing done in the XIB, mostly because I CANT since it's a XIB not a Storyboard.  I probably just need to make my own UITableViewCell and give it some defaults.

Comment: i have never used `UIImage.init(imageLiteral: "\(indexPath.row).jpg")`, i always use `UIImage(name: "\(indexPath.row).jpg")`, does it run?

Comment: changed to UIImage.init(named: ... same thing.

Comment: Try to use the image's size instead. image.size.width/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to achieve your goal:
Subclass the UITableViewCell, and override `layoutSubviews()`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView!.frame.size.width / 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I created a custom UITableViewCell .xib and .swift files.  This seems so simple though, I was hoping to use the default UITableViewCell class which already has a imageView in it.

Answer (score 2):

Below line wont layout any UIs yet, so you cannot get any kind of a dimention at this point.

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(imageLiteral: "\(indexPath.row).jpg")
```

One way is to get the image size

```
let image = UIImage.init(imageLiteral: "\(indexPath.row).jpg")
cell.imageView?.image = image
let size = image.size
```

Then do the rest with this size.

But if your images is too big then you may have to look into ways to resize it accordingly, because it will load the image according to size of the actual image, and it may not be as you expected.

Comment: Yes, this is what it's looking like, the cell has no dimensions yet.  The only thing with dimensions is my image and yes, it's not the size I want.  I'll try creating a custom XIB cell and give it some defaults.  I thought I could do this minimally using Apple's default UITableViewCell but looks like that's probably a NO.